# Interesting integral revolving around gamma function

Tags: calculus, contest-math

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$ $ \int_0^1$ $\sqrt[n]{x}$ $e^x$ $dx$

I came across this question whilst working for olympiad problems from Romania . I see a connection with the incomplete gamma function and a possible reccurence ny integrstion by parts although this should have a simpler solution . It may be relevant by shedding some light on lesser known aspects of more abstract elements . If anyone could help me somve this in simpler terms than that would be greatly appreciated , Thank you in advance .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the limit ? (For example by using a numerical software)

Comment: i have not tried one sadly

Comment: The cheap way to do this is to note that the dominated (or monotone) convergence theorems apply, and the integrand has an easily detected pointwise limit

Answer (score 2):

**Fact 1**

> The function series $f_N(x)=x^\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^N \frac{x^k}{k!}$ uniformly converges to $f(x)=x^\frac{1}{n}e^x$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

Proof: Note that
$$
|f_N(x)-f(x)|{=\left|x^\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right|
\\\le
\left|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}\right|
\\\le
\left|\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\right|
\\=
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+N)!}
\\\le
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{N!}
\\=\frac{e-1}{N!}.
}
$$
Since $\frac{e-1}{N!}$ can be arbitrarily small for sufficiently large $N$, the proof is complete $\blacksquare$

Using **Fact 1**, we can write
$$
\int_0^1 x^\frac{1}{n}e^xdx{=\int_0^1 x^\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}dx
\\=
\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{\frac{1}{n}+k}}{k!}dx
\\=
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!(k+\frac{1}{n}+1)},
}
$$
from which, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 x^\frac{1}{n}e^xdx=e-1.$$